# Non decreasing tuple for strict order

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let's say that we have a (non necessarily linear) strict order $(P, \prec )$ and a tuple of elements $a_1, ..., a_n  \in P$. Can we always find a permutation $\sigma : \lbrace 1, ... , n\rbrace \to \lbrace 1, ... , n\rbrace $ such that $a_{\sigma(n)} \not \succ a_{\sigma(m)}$ for all  $n < m$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) (where the directed graph to be topologically sorted is the given partial order).